Multiple table date constraint
I have 2 tables.
Product, which has an id (primary key).
Withdraw, which has an id (primary key), a product id (foreign key to Product), a date, and a state (ACTIVE, FINISHED).
A product is available only if it has never been withdrawn or if its last withdrawal (the most recent one) is FINISHED. The client needs to perform a search multiple times a day between available products.
I am looking for an efficient way to identify which products are available in order to show them to the client. I also want to avoid any logic outside the database (MySQL 5.7). The database must do all the work.
Based on my research, a TRIGGER seems to be my best bet.
Is there a solution I am not aware of?
Thanks in advance.
The final objective is to find a table like this:



id (product)
state




1
FINISHED


3
ACTIVE



A solution is to add a column 'last_withdrawal' (foreign key to Withdraw) to the Product table. The problem with this solution is that logic outside the database must be performed.

Join the Product table with a subquery that returns the latest row for each product from the Withdraw table.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 for how to write the subquery.

Use LEFT JOIN so you can get rows that have never been withdrawn.

Now that I've pointed you in the right direction, please show what you've tried and we'll help you fix it if it doesn't work.

Start with an upgrade of your MySQL version

note that mysql 5.7 is past end of life and no longer receiving security updates; consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as you can

I am aware of the fact that mysql 5.7 is deprecated. However, this is legacy software and it is mandatory not to update the database. Thanks for pointing that out.

A trigger which renews availability column in the product table (must be added) during the withdwraw insertion seems to be the most efficient solution. Separate additional table which stores tthe most last withdraw per product is intermediate one. A subquery is the least efficient but it does not need in additional onstructions.

I don't get it - what does 'A product is available only if it has never been withdrawn' ,mean? does it mean there are no entries in withdraw for that product? Does First withdrawal create a row with a data and status of active , there can follow many actives until a batch of actives is FINISHed? Sample source data would help clarify Following this logic  if ACTIVE surely product is not available so why does it show in your desired output.
